# Why is generator loss 0.00 but still produces white image in GAN?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function, generative-adversarial-network

I have created a GAN (Generative adversarial network) for creating CIFAR-100 images. The model runs fine but produces white images

My code is as follows (Colab notebook):

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter

device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
print(device)

tfs = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))]
)
train_data = datasets.CIFAR100('.', train = True, transform = tfs, download = True)
test_data = datasets.CIFAR100('.', train = False, transform = tfs, download = False)

idx = list(i for i in range(0, 10000))
train_data = torch.utils.data.Subset(train_data, idx)

batch_size = 100
train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = True, num_workers = 4)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = True, num_workers = 4)

class conv_layer(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, ks, strides = 1, padding = 1,
               normalize = True, dropout = 0.0):
    super(conv_layer, self).__init__()
    layer = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, ks, strides, padding)
    
    # Xavier He init
    nn.init.xavier_normal_(layer.weight)
    
    layers = [layer]
    if normalize:
      layers.append(nn.InstanceNorm2d(out_channels))
    layers.append(nn.ReLU())
    if dropout:
      layers.append(nn.Dropout(dropout))
    
    self.model = nn.Sequential(*layers)

  def forward(self, x):
    return self.model(x)

class Discriminator(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, img_channels):
    super(Discriminator, self).__init__()

    self.l1 = conv_layer(img_channels, 64, 3)
    self.l2 = conv_layer(64, 128, 3, 2, 0)
    self.l3 = conv_layer(128, 256, 3, 2, 0)
    self.l4 = conv_layer(256, 512, 3, 2, 0)
    self.l5 = conv_layer(512, 1, 3, 2, 0, dropout = 0.5)
    self.l6 = nn.Sigmoid()

  def forward(self, x):
    out = self.l1(x)
    out = self.l2(out)
    out = self.l3(out)
    out = self.l4(out)
    out = self.l5(out)
    out = self.l6(out)

    return out

class deconv_layer(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, ks, strides = 1, padding = 1,
               normalize = True):
    super(deconv_layer, self).__init__()
    conv_layer = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, ks, strides, padding)
    
    # Xavier He init
    nn.init.xavier_normal_(conv_layer.weight)
    
    layers = [conv_layer]
    if normalize:
      layers.append(nn.InstanceNorm2d(out_channels))
    layers.append(nn.LeakyReLU(0.2))
    
    self.model = nn.Sequential(*layers)

  def forward(self, x):
    return self.model(x)

class Generator(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, latent_dim, out_channel):
    super(Generator, self).__init__()

    self.l1 = nn.Linear(latent_dim, 256*4*4)
    self.l2 = deconv_layer(256, 128, 4, 2)
    self.l3 = deconv_layer(128, 128, 4, 2)
    self.l4 = deconv_layer(128, 128, 4, 2)
    self.l5 = nn.Conv2d(128, out_channel, 3, 1, 1)
    self.l6 = nn.Sigmoid()

  def forward(self, x):
    out = self.l1(x)
    out = out.reshape(-1, 256, 4, 4)
    out = self.l2(out)
    out = self.l3(out)
    out = self.l4(out)
    out = self.l5(out)
    out = self.l6(out)

    return out


image_shape = (3, 32, 32)
num_classes = 100
lr = 0.01
num_epochs = 500

latent_dim = 100
out_channel = image_shape[0]

gen = Generator(latent_dim, out_channel).to(device)
disc = Discriminator(out_channel).to(device)
optim_gen = torch.optim.Adam(gen.parameters(), lr = lr, weight_decay = 5e-4)
optim_disc = torch.optim.Adam(disc.parameters(), lr = lr, weight_decay = 3e-4)
criterion = nn.BCELoss()
criterion_gan = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

import os
import shutil
if os.path.exists('log/fake'):
  shutil.rmtree('log/fake')
if os.path.exists('log/real'):
  shutil.rmtree('log/real')

writer_fake = SummaryWriter('log/fake')
writer_real = SummaryWriter('log/real')
step = 0


%reload_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir log

z_dim = 100
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for id, (real, label) in enumerate(train_loader):       
        real = real.to(device)
        batch_size = real.shape[0]

        noise = torch.randn(batch_size, z_dim).to(device)
        fake = gen(noise)
        disc.zero_grad()
        
        # output of discriminator(real)
        disc_real = disc(real).view(-1)
        loss_real = criterion(disc_real, torch.ones_like(disc_real))

        # output of discriminator(fake)
        disc_fake = disc(fake.detach()).view(-1)
        loss_fake = criterion(disc_fake, torch.zeros_like(disc_fake))

        loss_disc = (loss_real + loss_fake) / 2
        
        loss_disc.backward()
        optim_disc.step()
        
        # Train generator
        gen.zero_grad()
        gen_image = gen(noise)
        loss_gen = criterion(gen_image, torch.ones_like(gen_image))
        
        loss_gen.backward()        
        optim_gen.step()
        


        if id == 0:
            print(
                f"Epoch [{epoch}/{num_epochs}] Batch {id}/{len(train_loader)} \
                      Loss D: {loss_disc:.4f}, loss G: {loss_gen:.4f}"
            )

            with torch.no_grad():
              fixed_noise = torch.randn((batch_size, z_dim)).to(device)
              fake = gen(fixed_noise)
              data = real
              img_grid_fake = torchvision.utils.make_grid(fake, normalize=True)
              img_grid_real = torchvision.utils.make_grid(data, normalize=True)

              writer_fake.add_image(
                  "Fake Images", img_grid_fake, global_step=step
              )
              writer_real.add_image(
                  "Real Images", img_grid_real, global_step=step
              )
              step += 1
```

I have ran it for few epochs and here is the log:

```
Epoch [0/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.7558
Epoch [1/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [2/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0010
Epoch [3/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0002
Epoch [4/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0004
Epoch [5/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [6/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0007
Epoch [7/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [8/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [9/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [10/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [11/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [12/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [13/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [14/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [15/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [16/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [17/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [18/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [19/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [20/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [21/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [22/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [23/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [24/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [25/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [26/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [27/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [28/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0002
Epoch [29/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [30/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [31/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [32/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [33/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [34/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0004
Epoch [35/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [36/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0004
Epoch [37/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [38/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [39/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [40/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [41/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [42/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [43/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0002
Epoch [44/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [45/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [46/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [47/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [48/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [49/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0002
Epoch [50/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [51/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0008
Epoch [52/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [53/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [54/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [55/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [56/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [57/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [58/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [59/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [60/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [61/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [62/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [63/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [64/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [65/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [66/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
Epoch [67/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [68/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [69/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [70/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [71/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [72/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0002
Epoch [73/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0000
Epoch [74/500] Batch 0/100                       Loss D: 0.6931, loss G: 0.0001
```

As you can see both discriminator and Generator losses are stagnant. The images produced are white blank images. I'm not able to understand the reason for this result. Kindly explain. Thankyou.

Comment: Have you inspected the tensors before they are going into the writer? They should be all 1 if they are being written? Or it's possible they are all very small values and then when you re-normalize them (with normalize=True, not sure why you are doing this?) they get spread up to a value of 1.

I'd also try making the learning rate a bit lower to adam's default levels and then decreasing the batch size a lot, even potentially batch size 1 to add more noise to the loss.